# Is it possible to read Azure Function webhook from within a function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

As part of an Azure function, we need to create webhooks in third party services that point back to our function. For this, we need to be able to retrieve the URL and secret within the function to include in our payloads.  I don't see it in the environment variables of the host, so is there any other place we can dynamically retrieve the secret or whole URL at runtime?

As a workaround, we can copy the value and put it in the App settings or environment variables, but we don't like doing that for every function app.

Comment: Can you share more details about your requirement? The recently introduced swagger support will give you the URL and API metadata, but won't expose the actual key (although it documents it).

Comment: Sure. It's exactly like what Kudu does does when a customer sets up continuous integration with Github/Bitbucket/Dropbox. Kudu makes an API call to the repository provider : "CreateWebhook".  The parameters of the API call include the callback URL and secret for the webhook to use.  Kudu then does a "pull" every time it receives a webhook for a push event.  Our application allows customers to specify repositories, which we will clone and perform our own business logic on from within an Azure function.  So, we need the hooks to come to our FunctionApp, and be authenticated of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported today. However, it is a potentially interesting idea. I suggest opening a tracking issue on https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues.